# Button Image disappear in custom cell while check the cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

When i check the cell using Accessory check mark in the table using below code

```
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
```

and then i click on the button of cell for expand sub category of that cell then the image of button disappear. i use below code to insert new cell under selected cell.

```
        [FieldtableView beginUpdates];
        for(int i=1;i<=cnt;i++)
        {
            NSIndexPath *pathforadd = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:[sender tag]];
            [FieldtableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:pathforadd]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
        [FieldtableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the button without a button action, does the button image disappear? 
I assume this isn't a problem.

When you just expand without a button click, does the button image disappear?
If it does, it may be related to the button image state. Just set the same image for UIControlStateHighlighted or UIControlStateSelected, not sure which one off hand.